# Editting text in c++ Scintilla box

Tags: c#, c++, scintilla

```
string selected = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
string add = selected + "/";
string path = add + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@path);
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
sb1.Append(text);
IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
IntPtr zero = new System.IntPtr(0);
var test = FindWindowEx(handle, zero, "RICHEDIT50W", null);
var but = FindWindowEx(handle, zero, "button", null);

StringBuilder nothing = new StringBuilder();
nothing.Append("");
SendMessage(test, WM_SETTEXT, 0, sb1);//sets text
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
SendMessage(but, BM_CLICK, 0, null);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
SendMessage(test, WM_SETTEXT, 0, nothing);
```

So I'm trying to Set the text of a Scintilla text box (C++) from a C# form. Before the program was updated it used a normal RICHEDIT textbox.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: trying to Set the text of a Scintilla text box (C++) from a C# form